# Cant run qgis version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API not defined

Tags: qt, qgis

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and I cant seem to get qgis to run anymore. The error I get is:

```
/usr/bin/qgis.bin: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5QuickWidgets.so.5: symbol _ZN15QQmlMemoryScope5stateE version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API not defined in file libQt5Qml.so.5 with link time reference
```

my qmake version is:

```
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.9.5 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

I have tried to link to qt5 but that did not change anything.

```
sudo ln -snf ../../../../share/qtchooser/qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf default.conf
```

Comment: What this error message indicates is that your application (qgis) is using a different version of Qt with which it was compiled. How did you install or compile qgis?

Comment: I used apt-get: sudo apt-get install qgis* python3-qgis*

Answer (score 1):

You need to uninstall QGIS and reinstall with the latest stable release. Using `sudo apt-get install qgis* python3-qgis*` to install is not precisely the best method because of the wildcard. The official instructions suggest using: `sudo apt install qgis qgis-plugin-grass`.

The instructions for best installation procedure on Ubuntu for LTS releases is posted [here](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu).

Comment: I first uninstalled using `sudo apt purge qgis* python3-qgis*` then reinstalled `sudo apt-get install qgis qgis-plugin-grass` and the same issue occurred. I tried following the exact process but there are numerous dependency errors.

Comment: You have QT or PyQT installed? Try removing those